# How to fix circular dependency issue?

Tags: c#, architecture, 3-tier

I have 3 Class Libraries, example below:

ApplicationCore (Main Class Library)

Application1 (Added Reference to ApplicationCore)

Application2 (Added Reference to ApplicationCore)

I would like to use Application 1 features in Application Core Class Library without a circular dependency issue. What is the best practice to implement features of Application1 to ApplicationCore?

Comment: Take those features and move them to ApplicationCore, then use them from Application1.

Answer (score 2):

Move the shared functionality to ApplicationCore, or a new shared class library.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is interfaces and dependency injection (DI).

- Create an interface in the MainClass Library. (ApplicationCore)
- Maybe have a default implementation of that interface in ApplicationCore.
- In Application1, setup the DI to user the implementation from Application1 for the interface.

In Application2 it will use the default implementation.

In Application1 it will use Application1's implementation.